# Building linq expressions on the fly

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sharepoint, expression

I need to build dynamic `LINQ` expressions on the fly.

This needs to be completely generic and dynamic. I am able to construct some of the simpler expressions but I am struggling to construct more complicated nested expressions.

For example I want to read and construct the following into an expression (dynamically in code)

```
(user = "me" and (status = "approved" or status = "rejected" 
or status = "new")) and (user = "james" and (priority = "important" 
or priority = "medium")) or (user = "jane" and (title = "something or title = "test"))
```

I want to convert this to an expression in the format of `Expression<Func<SPListItem, bool>>` which I can then pass over to a where clause.

Just to add that I am using `Camlex.NET` to convert this expression to a `Caml` query.

**Update:**

Tried this:

```
var inner = PredicateBuilder.False<SPListItem>();
inner = inner.Or(x => x["AssetStatus"] == (DataTypes.Choice)"Submitted - Awaiting Approval");
inner = inner.Or(x => x["AssetStatus"] == (DataTypes.Choice)"Reviewed - Awaiting Approval");
inner = inner.Or(x => x["AssetStatus"] == (DataTypes.Choice)"Approval overdue");

var outer = PredicateBuilder.True<SPListItem>();
outer = outer.And(x => x["IAO"] == (DataTypes.UserId)"1");
outer = outer.And(inner);

var inner2 = PredicateBuilder.False<SPListItem>();
inner2 = inner2.Or(x => x["AssetStatus"] == (DataTypes.Choice)"Review due");
inner2 = inner2.Or(x => x["AssetStatus"] == (DataTypes.Choice)"Review overdue");

var outer2 = PredicateBuilder.True<SPListItem>();
outer2 = outer2.And(x => x["PrimaryIAA"] == (DataTypes.UserId)"1");
outer2 = outer2.And(inner2);

var inner3 = PredicateBuilder.False<SPListItem>();
inner3 = inner3.Or(x => x["AssetStatus"] == (DataTypes.Choice)"Decommission requested");
inner3 = inner3.Or(x => x["AssetStatus"] == (DataTypes.Choice)"Decommissioning overdue");

var outer3 = PredicateBuilder.True<SPListItem>();
outer3 = outer3.And(x => x["IAO"] == (DataTypes.UserId)"1");
outer3 = outer3.And(inner3);

var fullQuery = outer.And(outer2).And(outer3);

return Camlex.Query().Where(fullQuery).ToCaml(false).FirstOrDefault().ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

But I get an error:

> Expression type 'Constant' is not supported

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) might be of use to you.

Comment: Tried that but I get an error: Expression type 'Constant' is not supported.

Comment: First try if you can use the expressions themselves in CAML. Maybe CAML doesn't support these string indexers.